# Each within each that is in an append for array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array which I am iterating over and displaying within some HTML.

The array of objects that is multidimensional. The main array is "data" with an object looking like:

[image]

The problem I face is, I want to loop through the 2nd array and display all the items which are relevant to the current array item being looped through.

The code below works 90%, in that is integrates over the nested array inside data which is called "screens". The only problem is when looping, it collates all the sub array values of screens into one and appends to the first #images div it finds.

What I want is for screens to append to the #images div relevant to its loop in the main $.each.

```
jQuery.each(data, function(i, val) {
  console.log(this);
  $('#result').append(
      '<div class="results__container large-12 columns ">' +
      '<div class="results__image large-2 columns">' +
      '<img src="//images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_' + size + '/' + val.packshot + '.jpg" />' +
      '</div> ' +
      '<div class="results__meta large-8 columns">' +
      "<div class='results--name'>" + val.name + "</div>" +
      "<div class='results--developer'>" + val.developer + "</div>" +
      "<div class='results--publisher'>" + val.publisher + "</div>" +
      "<div class='results--release'>" + val.release_date + "</div>" +
      "</div>" +
      "<div class='game-select large-1 columns end'><input class='squaredOne' type='checkbox' name='select_game'></div>" +
      '</div>'+
      '<div id="images-' + i + '" class="large-12">' +
      '</div>'
  );

  jQuery.each(val.screens, function(k, screen) {
      $('<div class="large-2 columns">' + screen + '</div>').appendTo('#images');
  })


});
```

Comment: Looks like all JS to me. If there is PHP add it and the tag.

Comment: You do know that you're adding multiple elements with the same ID here, right? It's not the best practice to have (`'<div id="images" class="large-12">' +`)

Comment: Updated, added the array key of that loop to the id

Comment: so now you just need to `$('<div class="large-2 columns">' + screen + '</div>').appendTo('#images-' + i);` (Updated my comment, changed `k` to `i`)

Comment: Ah perfect! Out of curiosity, how would you have done that if images was a class not an id?

Comment: @Kyon147 Since you're __appending__ each time to `#result`, you could use this selector instead `$('<div class="large-2 columns">' + screen + '</div>').appendTo('#result > .columns:last-of-type > .images');` (Should work, but I can't debug this)

Comment: Of course you need to change `<div id="images-' + i + '" class="large-12">' +` to `<div id="images-' + i + '" class="large-12 images">' +` (With or without the `id` attribute - It doesn't matter for my previous comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your last comment you asked me how you can append the screens into the correct image container, and I explained that since you're **appending** each time to `#result`, you could use this selector instead

```
$('<div class="large-2 columns">' + screen + '</div>').appendTo('#result > .columns:last-of-type > .images');
```

This way you're getting the `last-of-type` element with `columns` class.

You can also do the following

```
jQuery.each(data, function(i, val) {
  console.log(this);

  var html = '';
  jQuery.each(val.screens, function(k, screen) {
      html += '<div class="large-2 columns">' + screen + '</div>';
  });

  $('#result').append(
      '<div class="results__container large-12 columns ">' +
      '<div class="results__image large-2 columns">' +
      '<img src="//images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_' + size + '/' + val.packshot + '.jpg" />' +
      '</div> ' +
      '<div class="results__meta large-8 columns">' +
      "<div class='results--name'>" + val.name + "</div>" +
      "<div class='results--developer'>" + val.developer + "</div>" +
      "<div class='results--publisher'>" + val.publisher + "</div>" +
      "<div class='results--release'>" + val.release_date + "</div>" +
      "</div>" +
      "<div class='game-select large-1 columns end'><input class='squaredOne' type='checkbox' name='select_game'></div>" +
      '</div>'+
      '<div id="images-' + i + '" class="images large-12">' + html +
      '</div>'
  );

});
```

Now you first creating the scenes html code and appending it to the correct place. You also making fewer DOM searches so it's also better performances-wise.